# How to convert >> &#40060; >> to “鱼” in C#

Tags: c#, utf-8

below looks like a UTF8 encoding...

```
&#40060;
```

it appears as "鱼" in browser.

This string stored in database, how to convert that into the Chinese word in C#?

thanks

Comment: It's not UTF-8, it's an HTML entity. `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` will decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to HTML decode the string. for that you can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#40060;");
```